# Default SSL cert dir

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, asio

I have added support for loading HTTPS sites using asio following the example in the documentation which means I call `ctx.set_default_verify_paths();` to use the systems default paths for finding the certificates.

However with this I am getting: `unable to get local issuer certificate` and I notice that it's trying to use `/usr/local/ssl/certs` on my Ubuntu system.

But I don't even have that directory, instead the certificates seem to be in `/etc/ssl/certs` so if I am pointing the environment variable SSL_CERT_DIR there it works.

My question is how the default is picked up and how to change it, I don't know if my system is wrong or if the wrong directory is picked up from asio/ssl for some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the path can be [configured](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#PREFIX_and_OPENSSLDIR) when building OpenSSL using `--prefix` or `--openssldir`.

But to avoid recompiling OpenSSL another search path can be added like so:

```
ctx.add_verify_path("/etc/ssl/certs");
```